# Propel - get primary key after find

Tags: php, orm, propel

The question boils down to finding the proper way how to `getPrimaryKey` when iterating over a yielded result. When using `select` method, the result is an object of `ArrayCollection` which doesn't provide the `getPrimaryKey` method. A simple snippet

```
$q = UserQuery::create();
$q->select('a', 'b'); //yields an ArrayCollection object, doesn't have getPrimaryKey method when iterated
$q->find();
```

However,

```
$q = UserQuery::create();
$q->find(); //yields an ObjectCollection object, has getPrimaryKey method when iterated
```

### Update

I have tried to use the `setFormater` to force using the `ObjectCollection`. Ultimately, it resulted in exception being thrown.

```
$q = UserQuery::create()
         ->setFormater(ModelCriteria::FORMAT_OBJECT)
         ->select('a', 'b')
         ->find();  //Error populating object
```

### Update 2

Providing an exact use case, since it may be unclear at first what I am looking for. I have a table with `>100` columns. I am providing the functionality using `behaviour` to not disable (not `select`) some of them. Thus, I am unseting some of the columns, and basing the `$q->select` on the remaining ones.

```
if (!empty($tableQuery->tableColumnsDisable)) {
    $columns = $tableQuery->getTableMap()->getColumns();

    foreach ($columns as $index => $column) {
        if (!empty($tableQuery->tableColumnsDisable[$column->getName()])) {
            unset($columns[$index]);

            continue;
        }

        $columns[$index] = $column->getName();
    }

    //TODO - returns array collection, object collection needed
    $tableQuery->select($columns);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `select()`, Propel will skip object hydration and will just return an `ArrayCollection` containing an array for each result row.
To retrieve the `id` of each result row, you need to add the column name to the `select()`. You can then just retrieve the value from the row arrays by using the column name:

```
$users = UserQuery::create()
    ->select(['id', 'a', 'b'])
    ->orderBy('c')
    ->find();

foreach ($users as $user) {
    $id = $user['id'];
}
```

The select functionality is described in the [documentation](http://propelorm.org/documentation/reference/model-criteria.html#getting-columns-instead-of-objects) and in the docblock of `Propel\Runtime\ActiveQuery\ModelCriteria#select()` ([source](https://github.com/propelorm/Propel2/blob/2.0.0-alpha5/src/Propel/Runtime/ActiveQuery/ModelCriteria.php#L382)).

When you are using Propel 1, the functionality is the same. Read more about it in the [Propel 1 documentation](http://propelorm.org/Propel/reference/model-criteria.html#getting-columns-instead-of-objects) or the docblock of `ModelCriteria#select()` ([source](https://github.com/propelorm/Propel/blob/1.7.1/runtime/lib/query/ModelCriteria.php#L526)).

Comment: No, it is not said that `id` is the primary key. Moreover, the primary key can be (and will be in some cases) composite, meaning that is consists of more than just a single column. The goal here is to have `ObjectCollection` in order to have the `getPrimaryKey` working. Also, `setFormater` throws an exception (see the update).

Comment: You can replace `id` with whatever the name of your primary key column is. If you want to retrieve entity objects, you cannot use `select()`. This is because Propel needs all row data to be able to hydrate the objects.

Comment: The idea is that I am purposely not aware of the exact primary key columns. I am iterating over `tableMap->getColumns` and excluding some of them. I am using behaviours to generate some extra methods I need to provide. TL;DR - imagine a table with 100 columns. I am providing the functionality using behaviour to not disable (not select) some of them. Thus, I am unseting some of the columns, and basing the `q->select` on the remaining ones. Updated the question.

Comment: Gotcha; that's a pretty bad idea though. You would probably be better off either removing the columns from the database schema definition xml file or define separate views within your database so you can handle them within Propel the normal way. If you really want to go the dynamic select column route, you will need to manually hydrate the entities with the partial array data.

Comment: Finally, we are on the same track :) so my question to you is as follows: what is the best way to disable a column by not editing the schema but rather modifying the respective table/tableQuery subclass (that would the preferred in my case)?

Comment: You would probably need to override the object `hydrate` method to allow column values to not be defined in the `$row` data.